# Regex to extract all Starred Items URLs from Google Reader JSON file

Tags: html, regex, json, url

Sadly it was announced that Google Reader will be shutdown mid of the year.
Since I have a large amount of starred items in Google Reader I'd like to back them up.
This is possible via Google Reader takeout. It produces a file in `JSON` format.

Now I would like to extract all of the article urls out of this several MB large file.

At first I thought it would be best to use a regex for url but it seems to be better to extract the needed article urls by a regex to find just the article urls. This will prevent to also extract other urls that are not needed.

Here is a short example how parts of the json file looks:

```
"published" : 1359723602,
"updated" : 1359723602,
"canonical" : [ {
  "href" : "http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/02/omni-group-unveils-omnifocus-2-omniplan-omnioutliner-4-for-mac/"
} ],
"alternate" : [ {
  "href" : "http://feeds.arstechnica.com/~r/arstechnica/everything/~3/EphJmT-xTN4/",
  "type" : "text/html"
} ],
```

I just need the urls you can find here:

```
 "canonical" : [ {
  "href" : "http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/02/omni-group-unveils-omnifocus-2-omniplan-omnioutliner-4-for-mac/"
} ],
```

Perhaps anyone is in the mood to say how a regex have to look like to extract all these urls?

The benefit would be to have a quick and dirty way to extract starred items urls from Google Reader to import them in services like pocket or evernote, once processed.

Comment: Don't do this with regular expressions.  **Regular expressions are not a magic wand that you wave at every problem that happens to involve text.**  Use an existing, written, tested and debugged JSON library.

Comment: By the way, I too am sad about the closure of google reader.  I have found that http://www.bloglines.com/ is an acceptable replacement.  While not as responsive as reader, it has a pretty similar interface otherwise, and can import the OPML directly from the Google Takeout XML output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you asked about regex, but I think there's a better way to handle this problem. Multi-line regular expressions are a PITA, and in this case there's no need for that kind of brain damage.

I would start with `grep`, rather than a regex.  The `-A1` parameter says "return the line that matches, and one after":

```
grep -A1 "canonical" <file>
```

This will return lines like this:

```
"canonical" : [ {
    "href" : "http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/02/omni-group-unveils-omnifocus-2-omniplan-omnioutliner-4-for-mac/"
```

Then, I'd grep again for the href:

```
grep -A1 "canonical" <file> | grep "href"
```

giving

```
"href" : "http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/02/omni-group-unveils-omnifocus-2-omniplan-omnioutliner-4-for-mac/"
```

now I can use awk to get just the url:

```
grep -A1 "canonical" <file> | grep "href" | awk -F'" : "' '{ print $2 }'
```

which strips out the first quote on the url:

```
http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/02/omni-group-unveils-omnifocus-2-omniplan-omnioutliner-4-for-mac/"
```

Now I just need to get rid of the extra quote:

```
grep -A1 "canonical" <file> | grep "href" | awk -F'" : "' '{ print $2 }' | tr -d '"'
```

That's it!

```
http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/02/omni-group-unveils-omnifocus-2-omniplan-omnioutliner-4-for-mac/
```

Comment: great, that works as a charme. Could please give me a hint how i can additionally achieve to add some chars to every item? i'd like to make it like this <li><a href="http://www.stern.de/wirtschaft/geld/offshore-leaks-steuertrickser-prominent-steinreich-schamlos-1992983.html"></a></li>.

Comment: there are about 400 ways to do that too... perl might be my favorite: `... | perl -ne 'chomp; print "<li><a href=\"$_\">$_</a></li>\n"'`