# Import multiple URLs to Pocket (or Instapaper)

Tags: json, gmail, google-reader, instapaper, pocket

I'm trying to import all my old starred items from Google Reader into Pocket.  I have the JSON file and I've used grep to convert that to a simple text file listing all the URLs (thanks to PaulProgrammer here:  [Regex to extract all Starred Items URLs from Google Reader JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836671/regex-to-extract-all-starred-items-urls-from-google-reader-json-file)).

The problem now is - how do I get that into Pocket (or Instapaper)?

Does anyone have any ideas to do any of the below?

1. Import directly from the Google Reader JSON (this was the first thing I searched for and came up with several flawed partial solutions)
2. You can add URLs by e-mail, but only one at a time.  Maybe I can batch up a couple thousand e-mails through GMail somehow?
3. Any other ideas?

Here's a sample of my URL text file:

```
http://cheezburger.com/51746049
http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2013-05-24/
http://lifehacker.com/not-just-another-notes-app-why-you-should-use-google-k-509256637
http://digital-photography-school.com/save-time-with-batch-exposure-blending
http://mgoblog.com/content/what-big-ten-hockey-schedule-looks
http://digital-photography-school.com/how-to-photograph-star-trails
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this extension - [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/batch-save-pocket/ihhiomekhplpdojbcaniaglcfopckaef?hl=en) , which I have developed. Currently it does not support simple copy pasting of urls. But you can simply create an html page with the hyperlinks you need, open it in chrome and use the extension.

Edit - The extension now supports copy pasting of multiple urls.

Comment: Your answer deserves more upvotes. Was fighting with shell scripts and the API for hours until I decided to search for a simpler solution. This is basically everything I needed. The only problem I had was an error when I tried to import 1000+ links at once. That probably was too much for their API. Splitting it into batches of ~300 worked like a charm. Thank you for your work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`add`](http://getpocket.com/developer/docs/v3/modify#action_add) action from the [Pocket API](http://getpocket.com/developer/docs/overview) to add many links at once.

Sending an encoded JSON array like this should work:

```
[
    {
        "action" : "add",
        "url" : "http://cheezburger.com/51746049"
    },
    {
        "action" : "add",
        "url" : "http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2013-05-24/"
    }
    // truncated for brevity
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround for Instapaper, for someone who is still interested:

Instapaper allows importing articles from Pocket. So all you need is to put your links in an html file that has the same structure as the file you get when you export your Pocket articles.

Use the HTML file downloaded from Pocket as the template and replace the links with your list:

`<li><a href="LINK_1" time_added="1420736702" tags="">TITLE_1</a></li>`

Answer (score 1):

Convert your list to HTML file and import directly https://getpocket.com/import/browser